# Arduino for Simulink/MatLAB -- S-Function does not exist

Tags: matlab, arduino, simulink, s-function

I'm trying to run a simple SimuLink code, and everything has started to act strangely.

It's a basic program: take constant -> Send to PWM block.

I'm getting error in the command window: "Warning: Could not evaluate MaskDisplay commands of block 'Arduino_w_Camera/PWM': File "analogoutpwm.png" does not exist. "

Errors in the Diagnostics:  "Error in S-function 'Arduino_w_Camera/PWM/PWM': S-Function 'arduinoanalogoutput_sfcn' does not exist"

It seems like I may need to reinstall? But I just did that in an attempt to get rid of another problem, and now this is happening. Now it seems like all these reinstalled files are in the wrong place or something.

Any incite and help is appreciated.

Comment: What did you reinstall? Did you get arduino support package for Simulink?

Comment: I reinstalled the Arduino support packages for MatLAB and Arduino. I didn't reinstall all of MatLAB.

Comment: Simulink support package might be different from MATLAB. See https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/arduino/index.html.